# Configure Linux server to make it's VM's IP accessible from outside

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, web-server, virtual-machines

I have a physical Linux server (parent). I've installed a VM on that server (Virtualbox).
I've created a web project on that VM, and now it's accessible from `192.168.10.10`. But it's only accessible from the physical (parent) server.

How can I configure that physical server to forward incoming requests to it's VM IP address ?

For example, I can access my parent server with `http://80.80.80.80`, so whenever some visitor comes, he will see a content from `/var/www/html/index.html`.

Is there any chance to let the VM take the all incoming requests on it's own ?

Any tips or links to other similiar topics will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With VirtualBox you've got a few options. All is configured under the Settings - Network tab.

If you can get another public IPs in your network the easiest option is to set the Network Interface (NIC) to *Bridging mode*. Under *Settings -> Network -> Adapter1* change **Attached to: Bridged Adapter** and under **Name:** select the host network interface (e.g. `eth0`). That effectively exposes the guest (VM) Network Adapter to the same network as your host's `eth0`. The VM can then get its own public IP (e.g. 80.80.80.81) either statically assigned or DHCP.

If you can have only one IP (80.80.80.80) and can't get any more you will need to configure NAT and *Port Forwarding*. Again it's easily done under *Settings -> Network -> Adapter1*. Set **Attached to: NAT** and under *Port Forwarding* that appears at the bottom of the dialog box add forwarding for port 80. From now on anything that connects to 80.80.80.80 port 80 will be forwarded to the VM and handled there.

However in this case the caveat is that the *host* must not be running its own Apache or anything else listening on port 80. Alternatively if you're happy with using non-standard ports you can forward host's port 8080 to the guest's port 80 and the URL will then be http://80.80.80.80:8080 - this way you can have Apache on both the *host* and the *guest*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I think a NAT variation is OK for me. I forgot to mention that I have no GUI, only a terminal access via `ssh`. Do you think if it's still possible?

Answer (score 1):

Which network is your VM adapter attached to (Host-Only, NAT Network, Internal Network, Bridged Adapter)? To find out, select the VM>Settings>Network and check the attached-to options. Your could choose to use a bridged adapter in the network settings of the VM and expose the machine directly on the network and assign it an IP that is directly addressable (for instance, if the parent server is `http://80.80.80.80` with a `/24`, you could assign the VM an address within the same network, say `.81`)

Comment: It's NAT at the moment. I will try your suggestion and text you back. thank you

Comment: You can find detailed info [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) but the following command should accomplish what MLu described for the Port Forwarding: `VBoxManage modifyvm "Web VM name" --natpf1 "webserver,tcp,,80,,8080"`, where Web VM name refers to the name of the VM, natpf1 refers to the network adapter(1 in this case), webserver is descriptive and auto generated if not provided, tcp refers to the protocol (could be UDP), 8080 refers to port being forwarded on the host, and 80 is being forwarded to on the guest.